# How to create a new r dataframe variable contingent on existing variables

Tags: r, variables, if-statement, dataframe

Any suggestions on the best logic to create a new variable in a r data frame that is contingent on other variables in the dataframe?

Essentially, I have a type variable in one data frame that I want to overide in certian instances which are contained in a second dataframe.  Below is some sample data:

```
#### original data frame
id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6)
type=c("O", "O", "G", "O", "G", "O")
qty=c(10,20,30,40,50,60)
df1=data.frame(id, type, qty)

#### new dataframe with type override
id=c(2,4)
type_override=c("G", "G")
df2=data.frame(id,type_override)

#### dataframe with both origional and override type
df3=merge(df1, df2, by=c("id"), all.x=TRUE)

#### create new type variable that uses "type" for all variables
#### unless "type_override" calls for a override
df3$type_new= ???????
```

I would like to use the type classification (i.e. "type_override") in the second dataframe to override the type classification (i.e. "type" in the first dataframe.

I am an Excel user that is trying to make the transition to R, in Exel, I would just do something like:

```
type_newC1 = if(isna(type_overrideB1),typeA1,type_overrideB1)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Mike, and welcome to SO. If you ask a question, and one of the answers nicely addresses and solves it for you, you can "accept" it by clicking the check mark to its left. (Just thought I'd mention that in case you're not yet aware of that feature. You're under **no** obligation to accept (or vote on) answers, though doing so can help guide other users to the best answers.) Cheers.

Comment: Thank you.  I did not know about the "accept" feature so I appreciate you mentioning it.

Comment: No problem. From the effort you put into your questions, and your graciousness in response to the replies you've gotten, I figured that was the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your df2 will be used with only a single type, you can get away with a single step:

```
df1$type_override <- ifelse(df1$id %in% df2$id, df2$type_override, df1$type)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is almost identical to what you're used to in Excel:

```
df3$type_new <- ifelse(is.na(df3$type_override),df3$type,df3$type_override)
```

or if you want to save some typing, oftentimes R users will use `with`:

```
df3$type_new <- with(df3,ifelse(is.na(type_override),type,type_override))
```