# Create a new variable in a dataframe, the values of which are contingent on two other variables, in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a new variable in a dataframe, to indicate if someone has had surgery in 1988, or died in 1988, or if neither of these apply.

My data is similar to:

```
test <- data.frame(
ID = c(1:300),
hyst = c(rep(1985:2014, 10)),
death = c(rep(0,150),(rep(1985:2014,5)))
)
```

My new variable (test$y1988) should be 'Y' if they had surgery in 1988, but didn't die; 'D' if they died in 1988; and 'X' if neither occurred.
I tried this

```
test$y1988 <- for (i in nrow(test)) {
if(test$hyst[i] == 1988 & test$death[i] != 1988) {
"Y"
} else if (test$death[i] == 1988) {
"D"
} else {
"X"
}
}
```

The code appears to run, with no error message; but no new 'y1988' variable is created in 'test'.

I have seen these two questions, [How to create a new r dataframe variable contingent on existing variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775517/how-to-create-a-new-r-dataframe-variable-contingent-on-existing-variables); and 
[Creating a new variable in R from two existing ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48433604/creating-a-new-variable-in-r-from-two-existing-ones)
which are similar, but unfortunately I still can't get my code to work.

Comment: A tidyverse solution: `test %<>% mutate(y1988 = map2_chr(.x = hyst, .y = death, .f = ~ case_when(.x == 1988 & .y != 1988 ~ "Y", .y == 1988 ~ "D", 1 ~ "X")`

Comment: @JakeFisher - why do you need the `map2_chr()` bit - isn't this just a simple ifelse / case_when?

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, it is.  Thanks for reminding me.  I'll edit.

Comment: An updated tidyverse solution: `test %<>% mutate(y1988 = case_when(hyst == 1988 & death != 1988 ~ "Y", death == 1988 ~ "D", T ~ "X"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop isn't working for two reasons.  First, you needed to tell it to loop over `1:nrow(test)`, instead of `nrow(test)`, and second, you needed to tell R the particular row where it should assign new values of `test`.  The following code will run correctly:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(test)) {
  if(test$hyst[i] == 1988 & test$death[i] != 1988) {
    test$y1988[i] <- "Y"
  } else if (test$death[i] == 1988) {
    test$y1988[i] <- "D"
  } else {
    test$y1988[i] <- "X"
  }
}
```

You may also want to consider a vectorized solution.  In base R, you could do:

```
test$y1988 <- with(test, ifelse(hyst == 1988 & death != 1988, "Y",
                                ifelse(death == 1988, "D", "X")))
```

Or using the [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/) and magrittr, you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)  # for the %<>% command
test %<>% mutate(y1988 = case_when(hyst == 1988 & death != 1988 ~ "Y", death == 1988 ~ "D", T ~ "X"))
```

Comment: It's also essentially an interaction of the two variables being equal to `1988` - `interaction(data.frame(test[c("hyst","death")]==1988))` - e.g. `table(test$y1988, interaction(data.frame(test[c("hyst","death")]==1988)))` for comparison's sake.